# How to put a div above columns of flex displayed elements?

Tags: css, position, flexbox

I have a div that is displayed as flex. Inside the div are 3 other elements. I would like that the first element has 100% width and the 2nd and 3rd element should stay beside each other.

Sample code:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zByAEL)

```css
#flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#flex-container > .flex-item {
  -webkit-flex: auto;
  flex: auto;
}
#flex-container > .raw-item {
  width: 5rem;
}
#flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Consolas, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#flex-container > div {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 1rem;
}
#flex-container > .raw-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.fullwidth {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="fullwidth">full swidth</div>
  <div class="flex-item" id="flex">Flex box (click to toggle raw box)</div>
  <div class="raw-item" id="raw">Raw box</div>
</div>
```

Here I want to achieve that the yellow div (class = fullwidth) is 100% and above the 2 other elements, without changing the HTML and skipping flex.

Is there a way to achieve this properly?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `flex-wrap: wrap` on Flex-container and `flex: 0 0 100%` on div you want to take full-width. Also to make other div's equal width you can use `flex: 1`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#flex-container {
  font-family: Consolas, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#flex-container > div {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 1;
}
#flex-container > .raw-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#flex-container > div.fullwidth {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="fullwidth">full swidth</div>
  <div class="flex-item" id="flex">Flex box (click to toggle raw box)</div>
  <div class="raw-item" id="raw">Raw box</div>
</div>
```